# max32660 sudden uart slowdown above 3MBaud

Tags: microcontroller, uart

I am trying to set up UART1 for debugging on a MAX32660. At various  baudrates, I print `Hello, world!\n` 1000 times, and measure the time elapsed for each case.

```
140 bits/write,   14 characters/write

921600 baud: 149us / write      93Kcps
2MBaud:       69us / write     203Kcps
3.0MBaud:     47us / write     298Kcps
3.1MBaud:    691us / write      20Kcps
4MBaud:      551us / write      25Kcps
6MBaud:      382us / write      37Kcps
```

Why does the throughput *drop* as the baudrate increases above 3MHz?

Measurements are made and reported on the Tx side, and there is no flow control (Flow control is disabled via `UART_FLOW_DISABLE` in `sys_uart_cfg`). I am using `TMR_TO_Elapsed()` to make the measurements, and I checked it against my stopwatch in all cases, so it's not like the UART setting is affecting a common prescaler.

What could explain the sudden 16X transmission slowdown when the baudrate exceeds 3.0 MHz?

**Update** I hooked up a scope; the baudrate actually seems to be dropping about 16X. So maybe `uart.c` is not working right?

**Update** I read out `MXC_UART1->baud0`. The value is `0x00000001` not `0x00040001`. So the value of `FACTOR` is 0 instead of 4 as expected. This would exactly explain a 16X slowdown. But how can this be? Surely the baudrate code in the eval kit is right?

Per the above observation, perhaps hardware only supports FACTOR <= 3 (though I see nothing about this in the errata).

So I tried changing `MAX_FACTOR` to 3 in `uart.c`. While this leads to the correct setting of `baud0` and `baud1`, it appears that hardware runs at a very very slow baudrate if `baud0.ibaud==0`.

```
requested baudrate 3.0MHz:
baud0 = 00030001
baud1 = 00000003
actual baudrate: 3.0MHz

requested baudrate 3.1MHz:  (MAX_FACTOR = 4   -- uart.c as shipped from Maxim)
baud0 = 00000001
baud1 = 0000006d
actual baudrate: 200KHz

requested baudrate 3.1MHz:  (MAX_FACTOR = 3   -- uart.c modified)
baud0 = 00030000
baud1 = 00000075
actual baudrate: 1500Hz
```

I agree with the `uart.c` output in this last case. According to the user manual, it should yield a baudrate of:

```
DIV  = ibaud + dbaud/128
     = 0 + 0x75 = 0.91
baud = PeriphClk / [DIV * 2^(7-factor)]
     = 48MHz / [0.91 * 16] = 3.3MHz
```

which is the right speed to use, according to the framing error erratum (which itself gives me a great feeling too but enough on that topic).

Yet the observed baudrate (on the scope) is not 3.3MHz, but 1500Hz. Off by a tad.

Comment: How big is your buffer? On the PC side?

Comment: @DKNguyen The measurement is done (and reported) by the Tx side, and there is no flow control, so the receiver buffer can't matter. (The receiver is actually another MAX32660 because I couldn't find a decent serial adapter for Linux.)

Comment: What clock is your MCU being clocked at? And the clock to the UART (not the transmission clock). And how are you feeding the UART? DMA? Or interrupts? Maybe your UART is taking less cycles to transmit everything that the number of cycles processor is taking to keep the UART fed.

Comment: According to the datasheet maximum baud rate is 4000kbaud. Why are you trying to run it at 6Mbaud? _"Surely the baudrate code in the eval kit is right?"_ what code did your eval kit come with?

Comment: @Bruce Yeah I saw the 4Mbaud limit too. So forget the 6MBaud point. But 3.1Mbaud should definitely work, right? My eval kit came with "MAX32660 SDK", documentation version 2.7.5.0.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find anywhere to download or view that SDK. Suggest you try examining the source code or stepping though the program with a debugger to see what it does. Also carefully read documentation (including SDK and MCU errata) relating to baud rate selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Surely the baudrate code in the eval kit is right?

If found this assumtion untrue for non-standard baud rates in many eval kit code bases.

> 48MHz / [0.91 * 16] = 3.3MHz

Most UART implement restrictions for the divider, which usually must be bigger than either 1 or 2. In the manual chapter 8.4 it is specified as >=1 (one).

Comment: Thanks for the reference explaining DIV>=1. This is a partial answer. MAX_FACTOR=3 is still only partly explained (maybe the eval kit code is wrong as you suggest, but the part's user manual suggests that factor=4 should work). But it seems pretty clear that if factor=4 is written to the hardware, it reads back 0. So I'm still puzzled as to how they can claim 4MHz.